# MySQL trigger delete field after a period on update

Tags: mysql

I want to automatically delete recovery_url from table users 30 minutes after it's been updated. Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is using an additional column indicating how long the `recovery_url` is valid. It can be a `datetime` column and in your queries you can select the `recovery_url` depending on that date. So you don't need any triggers or events.

```
select case when url_valid_until < now()
            then null
            else recovery_url 
       end as recovery_url 
from your_table
```

Comment: I was hoping to use `SELECT SLEEP(1800)` to do it so I'm not reliant on polling the database..?

Comment: Keeping database connection open for 30 minutes is a very bad idea.

Comment: You don't need to poll anything if you use that condition when you select the DB.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it was possible to use conditions when selecting a database - please can you elucidate?

Comment: The case selects `recovery_url` if the `url_valid_until` > the current timestamp. Othwerwise `null` will be returned for `url_valid_until`

Comment: ... but wouldn't I need to call that from somewhere further down the line than MySQL? - or keep rerunning it somehow to test whether `url_valid_until` is less than `now()`?

Comment: If you need data from the table you run the select. With that contition it will always return the correct result. If you don't need to the data the don't select.